# Faking record id result in poor db performance?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, sqlite

I have modeled some data into a table, but privacy is a very important issue.  Whenever I create a new record I look for an unused random 9 digit id.  (This is to avoid anybody being able to infer the order in which records were created in a worst case scenario.)  By faking the id field do I risk losing database performance because it is used for addressing data in anyway?  For SQLite3?  This is a RubyonRails3 app and am still in a dev environment so not sure if SQLite3 will go to prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larger ID values do not make index lookups any slower.

Smaller values [use fewer bytes](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format) when stored in the database file, but the difference is unlikely to be noticeable.

For optimal performance, you should declare your `ID` column as [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) so that `ID` lookups do not need a separate index but can use the table structure itself as index.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE    Bargains
        (
            RowID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
            Code AS ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),
            CustomerID INT
        )

CREATE TABLE    Bargains
        (
            RowID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
            TheOtherBit VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), NEWID()),
            CustomerID INT
        )
```

We use NEWID() to generate a "random" value, take a few digits from that, put that in a SEPARATE field, and incorporate it in the "pretty value" shown to the user (and required when the user retrieves the data, but not required internally).

So we have

```
MyID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ...

TheOtherBit VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), NEWID())
```

but internally for us it would be ordered on RowID and of course u wont have to generate a number randomly either and the user does not get to see ur RowID...

Here is some working code to explain how u can create Unique ids within the database

```
USE TEST
GO
CREATE TABLE NEWID_TEST
(
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
TESTCOLUMN CHAR(2000) DEFAULT REPLICATE('X',2000)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE NEWSEQUENTIALID_TEST
(
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
TESTCOLUMN CHAR(2000) DEFAULT REPLICATE('X',2000)
)
GO

-- INSERT 1000 ROWS INTO EACH TEST TABLE
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = 1

WHILE (@COUNTER <= 50)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO NEWID_TEST DEFAULT VALUES
   INSERT INTO NEWSEQUENTIALID_TEST DEFAULT VALUES
   SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
END
GO

SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM NEWID_TEST
SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM NEWSEQUENTIALID_TEST
GO
```

Comment: ya sure, wudnt know abt that. was just trying to convey the idea really.. this is SQL Server code sure.. ya just checked that SQLite does not support newid() function.. There's nothing built into SQLite for this, but you can always create a custom function named "newid" that would generate a new unique guid.. basically my best guess is the function would use a random() inside it.. it is still better than self generating a random number and instead letting the DB take care of it by calling the newid() function in the insert statement, dont u think !